# Handle Infinispan POD Faults

Tags: java, kubernetes, infinispan, fault

I'm using the Java version of the Infinispan [library](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan).

I'm deploying Infinispan in two Kubernetes PODs and I have defined some replicated caches. Moreover, I have some microservices using such caches, connecting toward an Infinispan POD. Of course, the connection is made using the service name and the port. Indeed, my microservices are able to connect to one POD instance successfully at the end for using the remote caches.

Unluckily, when a POD had some fault and restarts, my microservice is not able to switch automatically to another replica POD of Infinispan, and issues begin to happen.

It's even worse when both POD restarts (I'm causing the restarts for robustness tests).

I was wondering if there's a way to notice when the POD a client is connected to becomes not available. For example, I use some Infinispan listeners to notice when certain operations are performed over the maps. Is there something similar for the service health? Maybe something keeping track of the distributed topology of the Infinispan cluster?

In case there's not, how do you handle these cases?

Comment: You have not specified the version. Hot Rod clients implement automatic failover and recovery, so I'm wondering about the configuration of your clients.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Tristan. I'm using Infinispan 12 as servers and Infinispan 14.0.4-Final as the Java client's library. For example, when both PODs restart, in my clients I'm able to see exception logs coming from Infinispan ("UnknownHostException"), and it's okay. But, when both PODs become running, it seems the references to the remote caches are "borken". It looks like the caches I've instantiated are pointing to the old PODs addresses still.

Comment: `RemoteCache`s don't point to server addresses. It's the `RemoteCacheManager` that tracks this. What client intelligence are you using ? Would it be possible to obtain `TRACE` logs of package `org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport` ?